# Камушек и камешек

Tags: стилистика

Вопрос об этих двух формах уже был - как выяснилось, возможны оба варианта. Но меня интересует другой нюанс: какую форму и когда уместнее употреблять? Часто встречаю в текстах вариант "камушек", но мне он кажется излишне сюсюкающим, а то время, как "камешек" - это просто маленький камень.
А как вы считаете?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ИЗ ТОЛКОВЫХ СЛОВАРЕЙ

Новый толково-словообразовательный словарь русского языка. Автор Т. Ф. Ефремова.
камушек м. разг. То же, что: камешек. Толковый словарь русского языка под ред. Д. Н. Ушакова  КАМУШЕК камушка, м. (разг.). То же, что камешек.

СЛОВООБРАЗОВАНИЕ:

Камень - камешек, суффикс ЕК, чередование Н/Ш в основе (основной вариант), камень - камушек, суффикс УШЕК, усечение основы (разговорный вариант).

ПРИМЕНЕНИЕ

Оба слова имеют уменьшительно-ласкательное значение, поэтому используются в в разговорном стиле одинаково часто, например:

На берегу реки лежал камушек. Обычный плоский серый камушек, галька. Расскажу вам сказку про бесценный камушек деда Павла. Камушки есть игра самая многосложная. Говорят, найти камушек с круглой дырочкой – к счастью. Как-то раз на день рождения Девочке подарили маленький сиреневый камешек. Камешек и пингвин мультфильм.

Но чаще можно встретить выражение "драгоценный камушек" - он такой "гранёный, КРУГЛЕНЬКИЙ, на солнце искрится". Почему-то кажется, что камешек - плоский, а камушек - круглый.

Answer (score 2):

> Часто встречаю в текстах вариант "камушек", но мне он кажется излишне сюсюкающим, 
> Мне нет. Наоборот, вариант нейтральный.
>
> а то время, как "камешек" - это просто маленький камень.
> Субъективно - есть стилистический акцет. Какой имеенно, не скажу. Поэтика, природа, может.

Answer (score 2):

Вот что пишет Розенталь:

В парах *воробышек* – *воробушек*, *камешек* – *камушек* первые варианты (с суфиксами -ышек, -ешек) употребляются в нейтральном стиле, а вторые (с суффиксом -ушек) имеют народный и разговорный оттенок.

В паре *краешек* – *краюшек* первому слову присущ разговорный оттенок, а второе является диалектным.

Answer (score -1):

Интересно, что ответы прямо не отвечают на вопрос — где уместно употреблять одну форму, а где другую.

Судя по ответам, которые не цитируют словари, которые тоже писали люди со своими предпочтениями и средами обитания, уместно употреблять ту форму, которую предпочитает аудитория, или важная её часть.